# Format value of data-win-bind attribute in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, winjs

Is there a way to format the value of the data-win-bind attribute (or any other data-* attribute) automatically in Visual Studio 2012 or Blend? I want to format the value to something like this:

```
<button data-win-bind="
    winControl.value: currentTime;
    winControl.min: startTime; 
    winControl.max: endTime; 
    winControl.progress: bufferedPercentage;
    winControl.onstart: onTimelineSliderStart PlayerFramework.Binding.setEventHandler;" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything like that built-in.

You could write an add-in to do that though without too much trouble. I wrote a "few" years back an add-in that would reformat XAML code in Visual Studio 2010 so that it would be more sensible (sorted and formatted and always put the x:Name/Id first). Also, you could also build a command-line tool you run periodically to fix up the syntax to your desired style.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm really looking for something already done because I currently don't have the time to do it myself. Thanks!